# In Kohana how does one dynamically specify column name while reading ORM data?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

Is it possible to do something like this? Obviously the echo statements I provided fail, is there a way to make them work with ORM?

```
$record_columns = $records->list_columns();
$records = $records->find_all();
foreach ($record_columns as $column) {
    echo $record->$column;
    echo $record[$column];
}
```

Thanks,

Serhiy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? For Kohana 3.0.x I am using this. I havn't tried it with Kohana 3.1 but it should be simular:

```
$result = ORM::factory('my_table')
   ->find_all();

$columns = Database::instance()
   ->list_columns('my_table');

foreach ($result as $row)
{
  foreach ($columns as $key => $value)
  {
    echo $row->{$key};
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, works just fine, thank you. Too bad I had already found a working solution.... I wound up using... $record->__get($column['column_name']))